# I have a context menu which is being shared by 6 different labels, how can I tell which label is using the current instance of the context menu?

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, label, contextmenu

Here is the xaml for the contextMenu:

```
    <Window.Resources>
    <ContextMenu x:Key="IBContextMenu" x:Shared="true" Name="IBContextMenu1">
        <MenuItem Header="Edit" Click="ibEdit_Click" AllowDrop="False" />
        <MenuItem Header="Clear" Click="ibClear_Click"/>
    </ContextMenu>
</Window.Resources>
```

Both the edit and clear items' methods need to know which label to act upon. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for `PlacementTarget`:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contextmenu.placementtarget.aspx

If you switch over to a Command-pattern, you can actually get this via Binding and pass it along as the CommandParameter...

Comment: This is the right answer, and doesn't require a work-around like mine. =)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer I came up with. I don't really like it because it's a bit hack-ish, but it works. The idea is that you make your labels listen to the `MouseRightButtonUp` event, which is fired when the user releases the right mouse button after clicking to open the context menu. In the event handler, you set a private Label variable to the label that the user just right-clicked. Then, in your MenuItem click handler, you can access that private Label variable. Note that **all** the labels you want to do this must use the **same** event handler for MouseRightButtonUp.

For example:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ContextMenu x:Key="MyMenu">
        <MenuItem Header="Edit" Click="Edit_Click"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Clear" Click="Clear_Click"/>
    </ContextMenu>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <Label ContextMenu="{StaticResource MyMenu}" 
           MouseRightButtonUp="Label_MouseRightButtonUp">Some text</Label>
    <Label ContextMenu="{StaticResource MyMenu}" 
           MouseRightButtonUp="Label_MouseRightButtonUp">Some junk</Label>
    <Label ContextMenu="{StaticResource MyMenu}" 
           MouseRightButtonUp="Label_MouseRightButtonUp">Some stuff</Label>
    <Label ContextMenu="{StaticResource MyMenu}"
           MouseRightButtonUp="Label_MouseRightButtonUp">Some 0000</Label>
</StackPanel>
```

Code behind:

```
private void Edit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (clickedLabel != null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(clickedLabel.Content.ToString());
    }
}

private void Clear_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (clickedLabel != null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(clickedLabel.Content.ToString());
    }
}

private Label clickedLabel;
private void Label_MouseRightButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    clickedLabel = (Label)sender;
}
```

Comment: FYI, in case anyone is thinking about doing this for Label's where IsTabStop = true (or for other Elements types that can have keyboard focus), it won't work if the Context Menu is opened via keyboard (i.e., via Shift+F10 or, if available, the Context Menu Key).

Answer (score 0):

Try to set a DataContext to the Labels, for example

And in the Click event just check the ((FrameworkElement)sender).DataContext for FIRST/SECOND etc. Let us know if that works.

Comment: But how would you set the data context of the menu to the lablel?

Comment: You dont need,  Whatever the DataContext of Label will pass to the MenuItem anyway.

Comment: I apologize if I take a while to respond, I haven't used data context before. Googling now.

Comment: I set the DataContext, but I don't know what I'm supposed to do now. I tried ((FrameworkElement)sender).DataContext.ToString, but I know that can't be right because it keeps returning: "MS.Internal.Data.XmlDataCollection"

Comment: this is not a good way to write software, it may work today but how will someone understand the code in a few years time or write tests for it?

Comment: Is there another way I could do it?